# How do I conditionally add a primary key to a database table using Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I need to craft a Liquibase migration script that adds a primary key to a database table only if that primary key hasn't been added already.  What is the best way to go about doing this?  It's going to be something like this:

```
<changeSet id="...">
  <preConditions>
    (What goes here? Should I use <sqlCheck>, or is there a better alternative?)
  </preConditions>
  <addPrimaryKey tableName="foo" columnNames="bar" constraintName="foo_pk" />
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And the answer is...

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
  <not>
    <primaryKeyExists tableName="foo" />
  </not>
</preConditions>
```